# Rails I18n validation deprecation warning, after setting enforce_available_locales = true

Tags: localization, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

You placed something like this in `config/application.rb`

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = true                                        
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config/locales/', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.available_locales = ['es-LA', :en]                               
config.i18n.default_locale = 'es-LA'
```

And the warning still appears:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future.
```

Comment: For others stumbling upon this with search, check the ruby on rails guides, configuring rails, i18n.  This edge docs link has the latest: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-i18n  My app is still Rails 3.1 (yes, I know, get busy…) This new i18n deprecation slipped in with a minor update.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is due to a bug with locales that have the language-country format. The good news is that it has been fixed already. This was reported in Github with [Issue 13164](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13164) and fixed with [pull request 229](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/pull/229).

If you want to grab the latest code with the fix, update the gem like this:

Update your Gemfile with:

```
gem 'i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/i18n'
```

And then: `bundle install`

Comment: Will this somehow break the normal bundle mechanism? Do I have to do this, or will the error go away automatically after some time when I do `bundle update`?

Comment: Your gem will be updated to whatever is the latest commit in the master repository, you'll keep on getting the latest code always. If you feel like a future update might break things, you can do it just once to get the relevant bug fix, and then delete the github part in the Gemfile.

Comment: Probably the error will go away after a `bundle update`, provided you don't have a version lock or the likes. I don't know when this could be, most likely until a new version of the gem comes out.