# enforce_available_locales deprecated tab what does this mean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

When running cucumber tests I get the following error:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
```

What does this mean and the suggestion that it gives about skipping validation?  Why would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is due to a bug in the i18n gem that is shipped with rails 4.0.2

Solution is either to add this line in your *config/application.rb*

```
config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = false
```

Either to use github repository for i18n gem, as mentioned in this post: [Rails I18n validation deprecation warning, after setting enforce_available_locales = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487127/rails-i18n-validation-deprecation-warning-after-setting-enforce-available-local)

It should be fixed in a future version

Comment: Does this bug affect cucumber tests passing?

Comment: No, It's just a warning