# Where to place I18n.enforce_available_locales = false

Tags: passenger

I am trying to run Phusion Passenger and this is the furthest I got. When it loads up on the website it comes up

require 'rails/all'... 0.550s
Bundler.require... 1.510s
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
Application.initialize!... !> Error

Where do I put I18n.enforce_available_locales = false and will this solve my issue?

Comment: Actually, I didn't post the error at the top.

Comment: An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It sent an unknown response type "\n".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails I18n validation deprecation warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361428/rails-i18n-validation-deprecation-warning)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will solve the error.
You need to put

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
```

into your application.rb file so that it looks like this

```
...
module FoodDump
  class Application < Rails::Application
     ...
     I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
     ...
  end
end
```