# Deploy Rails 4.0.2 on Heroku locale deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've updated to Rails 4.0.2 and I got the deprecation warning:

> [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in
>   the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you
>   can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.

To get rid of the warning, I decided to set:

```
I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = true
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
```

in my config/application.rb file.

It worked on Development but when I deploy my work to Heroku I get following error:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       :es is not a valid locale
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n.rb:288:in `enforce_available_locales!'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/config.rb:32:in `default_locale='
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n.rb:35:in `default_locale='
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:41:in `block in initialize_i18n'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:34:in `each'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:34:in `initialize_i18n'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:15:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_e6bd0f83-f9f7-45ad-9d98-13384d9403dc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
```

Any ideas how to avoid this error?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `config/locales/es.yml` file?

Comment: Yes, I have config/locales/es.yml and also locale file for devise (devise.es.yml) and simple_form (simple_form.es.yml)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should work if you set `config.i18n.available_locales = [:es]` first.

Comment: If I set config.i18n.available_locales = :es i get following error on development
`
:/home/abibiano/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n.rb:288:in `enforce_available_locales!': :en is not a valid locale (I18n::InvalidLocale)
 from /home/abibiano/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n.rb:234:in `transliterate'
 from /home/abibiano/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/transliterate.rb:62:in ...
`

Comment: What if you set it to [:en, :es]?

Answer (score 1):

This bug:

> The reason is due to a bug with locales that have the language-country
>   format. The good news is that it has been fixed already. This was
>   reported in Github with [Issue 13164](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13164) and fixed with pull [request 229](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/pull/229).

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361428/rails-i18n-validation-deprecation-warning) for more info

`config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = boolean`

**if you use false:** 
this skip the locale validation
don't care about locales

**if you use true:** 
want the application to raise an error if an invalid locale is passed (or)
want to default to the new Rails behaviors (or)
care about locale validation

Comment: I think this issue is not related with this bug because if I set it to false I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = false all works fine

Comment: https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/commit/2893ebf4674a12fcded5779ad13fa05dc74dbf5e