# I18n deprecation warning when using ActiveModel without Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activemodel, rails-i18n

When I run Rspec on my models, I get this warning:

> [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in
>   the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you
>   can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.

I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361428/rails-i18n-validation-deprecation-warning) where the solution was to set `config.i18n.enforce_available_locales` or
`I18n.config.enforce_available_locales` in my config/application.rb file. I tried both, but I still get the warning.

The test that gives me the deprecation warning does not use any Rails except for ActiveModel. Instead of requiring the default spec_helper, I created my own spec_helper that does not involve any Rails at all. I also tried setting enforce_available_locales in my custom spec_helper, but I got an uninitialized constant error.

**How do I get rid of the deprecation warning?**

**Edit:**
Here's the exact code in my config/application.rb from one of my attempts with enforce_available_locales

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Microblog
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = true
  end
end
```

Comment: what exact code did you write in your `application.rb`? Because that is indeed the correct fix. This will likely get flagged as duplicate.

Comment: what is your gem 'i18n' version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to work is adding these lines to my spec_helper:

```
require 'i18n'
I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = true
```

Because my tests don't use Rails, the Application class goes untouched, so enforce_available_locales must go in the spec_helper itself. The first line gets rid of the uninitialized constant error.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a bug reported on `i18n` in Github regarding this ([svenfuchs/i18n#223](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/pull/223)) and it was said to be fixed in `i18n` gem version `0.6.9`.

So the solution I think is to require '>= 0.6.9' in our Gemfile.

```
gem 'i18n', '>= 0.6.9'
```

and do a `bundle update`.

Then do as below:

**config/application.rb**

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = true

# If you set the default_locale option you should do it after the previous line
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de
```

Ref: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13159

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Then make changes in config/application.rb only. It is fixed in my machine with the above update. My app is also using i18n 0.6.9. Does it work for you?

Comment: if you change `I18n.enforce_available_locales = true` to `config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true`?

Comment: Yes. I haven't changed any locale settings.