# I18n validation deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated, rails-i18n

Hi I can't precompile my assets because of this "I18n validation deprecation warning". I've tried the answers here [Rails I18n validation deprecation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361428/rails-i18n-validation-deprecation-warning) but nothing seems to work. I am using rails 3.2.11, windows7 64bt and here's my trace:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your loc
ale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=as
sets --trace
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your loc
ale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your loc
ale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
```

Comment: these are warnings - they do not interfere with the compilation of your assets. It looks like the compilation is completing successfully based on this log.

Comment: but the changes in my assets was not applied after precompiling.

Comment: did you save the changes? what were the changes?

Comment: yes. i just added some changes in my javascript, just a function that limits the number of words in a textarea, but when i try to run `heroku run rake assets:precompile --app <app_name>` and check my app, the changes were not applied.

Comment: did you commit your changes into your git repository and then push them to heroku?

Comment: yes. the changes that are not included in the assets were applied i also checked the HEAD of my app and it is on my latest commit.

Comment: for avoiding the deprecation warning, refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401281/i18n-deprecation-warning-when-using-activemodel-without-rails?answertab=votes#tab-top. But, it is not really the warning making the issue.

Comment: tried that. but still i can't precompile