# Rails I18n deprecation warning on a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, deprecated

Related to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361428/rails-i18n-validation-deprecation-warning/20381730), I have a gem that uses rails 4.1.8 and rspec 2.99. When I run my rspec suite I get the deprecation notice:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
```

In the linked post, the solution was to add `config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = true` to the `application.rb`; however, there is no such file for gem and I don't know where to set configuration settings for a gem.

**Update**

I tried adding this statement into my `railtie.rb` as that seemed to be implied in the [Railtie documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html), but that doesn't seem to have any effect.