# Rails Controller is taking long time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, request

I created a new rails application.
When I make some request, it takes around 30 seconds to start processing

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def test
    puts "=================" # this only apeears after 30 seconds from the request time.
    result = { key: 'value' }
    render json: result
  end

end
```

Then it process everything correctly and returns my response in JSON (the inside controller code is ok).

My problem is the time until the request arrive on the controller.. What could it be?

NOTE: I'm not using any database.

EDIT: log/development.log and config/aplication.rb

log/development.log

```
Started GET "/run" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-11-26 16:00:12 +0000
Processing by TesteController#run as HTML
  Parameters: {}
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.8ms)


Started GET "/run" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-11-26 16:02:19 +0000
Processing by TesteController#run as HTML
  Parameters: {}
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.9ms)


Started GET "/run" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-11-26 16:02:23 +0000
Processing by TesteController#run as HTML
  Parameters: {}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.9ms)
```

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module DataMining
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'

    # This line removes the deprecation warning about validation of locales, and
    # probably won't be needed in future Rails versions.
    # More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361428/#answer-20381730
    config.i18n.enforce_available_locales = false

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    config.i18n.default_locale = 'pt-BR'
    config.i18n.locale = 'pt-BR'

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    #config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show any before filters in test controller and application controller?
Also routes

Comment: You should also check the log of your application to see what's going on: `tail -f log/development.log`

Comment: I'm not using any filter and everything is ok on log.

Comment: It would be better if you provide your log

Comment: please show `config/application.rb`.

Comment: The logs you posted are a request to another action of another controller. Can you post some logs for the actual problem happening?